# Errors associated with Webpack mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

```
I have four Errors associated with Webpack, how do I go about removing them. I have provided my Access code for reference. I am using a dotenv and importing it  mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX}
```

---

```
**Errors**
Failed to compile.

SyntaxError: Error parsing /Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/path-exists/package.json: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
    at parse (<anonymous>)
asset static/js/bundle.js 46.1 KiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset index.html 719 bytes [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 190 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 27.1 KiB 9 modules
modules with errors 156 bytes [errors]
  ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js 39 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [1 error]
  ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10 39 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [1 error]
  ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 39 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [1 error]
  ./src/index.js 39 bytes [not cacheable] [built] [1 error]
```

ERROR in ./src/index.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    SyntaxError: Error parsing /Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/path-exists/package.json: Unexpected token )
        at readPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:304:20)
        at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:479:15)
        at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
        at Object. (/Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/find-up/index.js:4:20)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)

    
    ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    SyntaxError: Error parsing /Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/path-exists/package.json: Unexpected token )
        at readPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:304:20)
        at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:479:15)
        at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
        at Object. (/Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/find-up/index.js:4:20)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    
    ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    SyntaxError: Error parsing /Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/path-exists/package.json: Unexpected token )
        at readPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:304:20)
        at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:479:15)
        at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
        at Object. (/Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/find-up/index.js:4:20)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Error parsing /Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/path-exists/package.json: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at readPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:304:20)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:479:15)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shansiddiqui/Desktop/weeWee/client/node_modules/pkg-dir/node_modules/find-up/index.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)

webpack 5.66.0 compiled with 4 errors in 9833 ms
```